# How to write Laravel routes URIs that match a pattern

Tags: laravel-routing

This might be pretty simple i believe but i am stuck and with no much info around.
I have seen pattern matching with route parameters but not with route URIs.
So, what i want to do is to write a route that loks something like this: `Route::get('books/*')` which can take any URI that starts with books.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got a bit wrong'y code:

```
Route::get('games/{rest}', 'GameController@showRest')
        ->where('rest', '(.*)');
```

in your code `Route::get('books/*')` at least should be `Route::get('books/.*')`

`*` does not mean anything but any number of character, `.` does